# Show warning on page only when IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, ie8-compatibility-mode

I want to show a warning on a particular page I have if and only if the user is using IE 7.

I am currently seeing an issue where if the user is using IE 8 in compatibility mode they are seeing this warning message, the logic is as follows:

Please note: Some customers using Internet Explorer 7 web browser may not be able to use parts of this site. You may wish to upgrade.

How can I fix the page so that the customer is only shown this warning if they are really using IE7?

Answer (score 0):

The specifics depends on the web framework in use (asp.net etc), but you can check the browser version by checking the user agent submitted by the browser. Each browser will have a unique user agent that includes the version number as well. The user agent will be in the http request.

Here's a link with a few options if you're using asp.net
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $buoop = {vs:{i:7,f:5,o:12,s:5,n:9}}; 
$buoop.ol = window.onload; 
window.onload=function(){ 
 try {if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();}catch (e) {} 
 var e = document.createElement("script"); 
 e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"); 
 e.setAttribute("src", "//browser-update.org/update.js"); 
 document.body.appendChild(e); 
} 
</script>
```